# How to output an awk command into a specific format and save to a file?

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to output a list of video file names into a specifig format using awk. The output should be saved to a txt file.

For example, I have the following list of video files:

```
01-20191006184929.mkv
02-2019.mkv
```

and the desired output would be:

```
file 01-20191006184929.mkv
file 02-2019.mkv
```

My current script just outputs the file name. How do I add "file" in front of each line?
That's my current script:

```
ls | awk '/.mkv$/' > output.txt
```

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You possibly can use awk, but this is easier using shell command:

```
printf "file %s\n" *.mkv > output.txt
```

`printf`is a builtin shell command that outputs the string referred in between double quote for each mkv filename.

Note: [Don't parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Nice! That's even simpler that my approach

Answer (score 1):

We shouldn't parse `ls` output, you could try with `for` loop.

```
for file_name in *.mkv
do
   echo "file $file_name"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate why we shouldn't use "ls" for output? Also, I need the script to output the result to a txt file (sorry, I will add that to the question)

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev, See this link once https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhiev, Ok I just now saw, Olive also has pasted same link :)

Comment: Thanks! I will have a read. I am new to Linux and shell scripting so that will be informative :)

Answer (score 1):

And using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)print "file",ARGV[i]}' *.mkv
```

Output:

```
file 01-20191006184929.mkv
file 02-2019.mkv
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {                       # no need to touch the files
    for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)       # for all parameter filenames
        print "file",ARGV[i]  # print
}' *.mkv                      # filename set goes here
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accepted oliv's answer as it's a much simpler approach to mine with using awk. However, it's very informative to know how that can be done with awk.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
$ stat -c "file %n" *mkv
$ find -name '*mkv' -printf "name %p\n"
```